# How can I get the path of image file?

Tags: image, email, react-native, path, screenshot

This is my function for capturing screenshots. Now I need the path of currently captured screenshot. Because I want to attach the captured image with a mail. So I need that path of image. How can I get the path of image?

```js
takeSnap() {
    var albumName="ShilpaMela";
    image=captureScreen({
      format: "jpg",
      quality: 0.8
    })
    .then(
      uri => {
        CameraRollExtended.saveToCameraRoll({
          uri: uri,
          album: albumName
        }, 'photo')
      },
      error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
    );
  }
```

```js
handleEmail = () => {
    Mailer.mail({
      subject: 'Help',
      recipients: ['support@example.com'],
      ccRecipients: ['supportCC@example.com'],
      bccRecipients: ['supportBCC@example.com'],
      body: '<b>A Bold Body </b>',
      isHTML: true,
      attachment: {
        path: this.state.imageUri,  // The absolute path of the file from which to read data.
        type: 'jpg',   // Mime Type: jpg, png, doc, ppt, html, pdf
        name: '',   // Optional: Custom filename for attachment
      }
    }, (error, event) => {
      Alert.alert(
        error,
        event,
        [
          {text: 'Ok', onPress: () => console.log('OK: Email Error Response')},
          {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('CANCEL: Email Error Response')}
        ],
        { cancelable: true }
      )
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the path to your `state` from `uri`

```
takeSnap() {
    var albumName="ShilpaMela";
    image=captureScreen({
        format: "jpg",
        quality: 0.8
    })
        .then(
            uri => {
                this.setState({imageUri: uri}) //save path
                CameraRollExtended.saveToCameraRoll({
                    uri: uri,
                    album: albumName
                }, 'photo')
            },
            error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
        );
}
```

and get the path using `this.state.imageUri`

**P.S**: Make sure function `takeSnap` is `bind` with `this`

Comment: Now it does not show the message "Cant attach file" but doesn't attach anything to the mail. Is there need to add anything else to the attachment code?

Code:
attachment: {
        path: this.state.imageUri
}

Comment: check  `console.log(this.state.imageUri)` in your attachment code. Is it empty? and please show your full code for attachment.

Comment: I edit my post and add the code of email function. Please check.

Comment: Did you check the value of `this.state.imageUri` in `handleEmail` function? Is it empty or not?

Comment: its empty. checked it now. but why? didn't understand.

Comment: `this.takeSnap = this.takeSnap.bind(this);` add this code in your `constructor` function.

Comment: Please try `console.log(uri)` in  `takeSnap` and check whether it's empty or not.

Comment: its empty. uri not exist here. its not empty after saveTocameraRoll() but the problem is first it compiling half of takeSnap() and after that it calls handleEmail() and finally it run ".then" part of takeSnap().

Comment: Then you have to set the `state` when the `uri` is not empty.

Comment: I tried that but this code run at the last because I use there ".then()". is there any alternative way of using .then() ? because it run at the last if I use .then() and I can't get the uri before I use it in another function.

Comment: this problem solved but new problem starts. this uri is a temporary uri. this file not exists after save the file. the saved file uri is different. I need that saved file uri. saveToCameraRoll() saved this file. I need that location. Are you know any way to do this?

Comment: Dear, tell me which library you're using to capture screenshots?

Comment: import { captureScreen } from "react-native-view-shot";